# Subscribe to all control values within an dynamic array of controls

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a dynamic array of ng-select controls. Each control represented by class [NgSelectComponent](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/ng-select/lib/ng-select.component.ts#L73).

When select value changes I want to subscribe to all controls.

Template

```
  <ng-select #select">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="select.id">{{ option.name }}</ng-option>
  </ng-select>
```

Class

```
  @ViewChildren('select') controls: QueryList<NgSelectComponent>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    concat(this.controls.toArray()).subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
```

I try that, but does not work.

```
concat(this.components.toArray()).subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

I believe it does not work because I had to subscribe to the values produced by each control corresponded by [changeEvent](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/ng-select/lib/ng-select.component.ts#L156) but struggling to do that.

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `concat` will likely not work. With `concat`, each observable in the array will wait for the previous to complete. This is probably not the behaviour you are expecting here.

You may use `merge` which will simply forwards all the emitted values to the output Observable individually. Or use `combineLatest` if you want an array of all the current values, whenever one Observable emits.

To convert the `valueChanges` of the `controls` to an array, use a `map`.

```
merge(
  ...this.controls.toArray().map(c => c.changeEvent.asObservable())
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: seems `valueChanges` does not exist in there, I try `changeEvent` but does not work even trying that with `merge`

Comment: it specified in the question, here it is https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/ng-select/lib/ng-select.component.ts#L73

Comment: it seems that `changeEvent` is the one, but no luck

Comment: @sreginogemoh - I edited my answer. Can you try that?

Comment: just did, all same..., I put custom `(change)` event to debug just to see if controls does trigger single the changes, and it does, but this approach does not..

Comment: also if I do this, it works `this.controls.toArray()[0].changeEvent.subscribe(console.log())`

Comment: did you try it with `merge` instead of `concat` ?

Comment: yes, tried both, does not work either of them

Comment: I got one more idea. Add the spread operator in the `merge`

Comment: it does work now using spread operator, I wonder why?

Comment: However say I have 3 controls there, so current rxjs code seems return only one latest selected, is there any way to accumulate the values by id so once all set to run the subscribe logic?

Comment: The `merge` method does not actually accept an array. It has a *rest parameter*. Thats why spreading works. You could use `combineLatest` (without the spread) to get an array of all values. But the other ones won't be blank. They will have their latest values as well.

Comment: I guess you would need some sort of state to keep track which have already been selected.

Comment: oh right, that is interesting, the `combineLatest` seems works exactly like that, accumulating the values, unless all set there is no emit, right? and then once you change one it brings the others previous values as well.

Comment: @sreginogemoh - yes, exactly

Comment: I am using `combineLatest` with a spread

Comment: yeah, seems like `comineLatest` accepts both arrays and spread arguments. But I think the spread argument is deprecated here. So its better to pass an array

Comment: I changed to nospread and it works too, I will keep that. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is what [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) are for. You create a `FormArray` and have `FormControl`s in there. Then you can subscribe to the `valueChanges` observable of the `FormControl`s. I highly recommend you to rewrite the code using this angular feature.

That being said, the easiest and more let's say unrefined solution is to use the changeEvent as you said:

```html
<ng-select #select (change)="selectChanged($event)">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="select.id">{{ option.name }}</ng-option>
  </ng-select>
```

```js
selectChanged($event) {
  // This function is called every time any select is changed.
  // If you want, you can create a Subject and .next() the values there to have an Observable
  console.log($event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: it seems following this approach you have to use dynamic forms approach https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form ?

Comment: Yeah, that approach is probably perfect for your use-case.

Comment: yes, thank you for suggestion, I will +1 that and might try that later but accepting the other answer as it was helpful and works